# Python - How to check values in a sublist

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

I'm trying to append a sublist to a larger list of the same type of sublist.

Sublist:

```
[x-value,y-value, i, 100]
```

However, I would like my code to check if there is already a sublist that has the same x-value and y-value before adding it, so that, in this case, I don't have overlapping trees (don't ask).

This is how i'm building the list:

```
food = []
 for i in range(amount): 
        food.append([
            randint(100, 700), #X
            randint(100, 700), #Y
            i, #identifier
            100]) #energy
```

Comment: I would just use a dictionary with `(x,y)` tuples as keys and `[id, energy]` as values.

Comment: It feels like this question is asking for someone to write the code which is a solution… This is generally discouraged on StackOverflow. You'll probably have more luck if you ask a more specific question (for example, "how do I determine whether a list contains overlapping values?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to ensure uniqueness of the `(x, y)` values and you have data to associate with them, this is the perfect use case for a dictionary:

```
food = {}
for i in range(amount):
    coords = randint(100, 700), randint(100, 700)
    if coords not in food:
        food[coords] = [
            i,   #identifier
            100, # energy
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks, since my programming course is quite patchy we haven't done dictionaries yet, I realize I should just have read about them in advance though. This seems to solve my problem very nicely, thanks a lot for the speedy answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
food = []
for i in range(amount):
    x,y = randint(100, 700),randint(100, 700)
    value = [x,y,i,100]
    if  all([True if x[0]!=x and x[1]!=y else False for x in food]): #check for duplicated x,y
        food.append(value)
```

Comment: yeah, i just realize that now didn't properly read the question will  try to come up with a fix

Comment: first think i thought as well... Using a dictionary as @Platinum Azure is probably the best way

Comment: That's what I thought (see comment under the answer), five minutes before PlatinumAzure posted his/her answer ;)

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, my answer was inspired ;-) You could have beaten me to the answer, but... you didn't :-P

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using "in", or a dictionary sorting them lexicographically might be better way to go. Then use a 2D binary search to find the what you seek.

Though this probably only useful if you're expecting a lot of duplicates, otherwise a simple linear search would be sufficient.

Note: Originally, sort by distance was suggested, upon reflection, this sort isn't very helpful in the situation.

Comment: The order for distance is the same as the order for the distance squared, so there is no need to take the sqrt for the sort

Comment: Thanks, it was intended to be math.sqrt((x1-x2) ** 2 - (y1-y2) ** 2. Changed it to just allow for a distance function to be used instead.

Comment: Changed to lexicographic sorting.